When house water pump is off and pressure tank empty, is the water pressure tank supposed to loose air pressure?
Pressure tank won't hold air. Leaks out.

I believe most of them are not repairable, so you are looking at a replacement of the tank.

Seeing tanks are pre charged it should maintain air pressure whether full of water or empty.

They should maintain pressure unless there is a leak.  An empty tank will not have any pressure against the leak, so it can leak easier.  If just a pin hole  a full tank might slow down the leak enough to not be as noticeable.

I think the only leaks repairable on those tanks is the air pig/valve that can be tighten or replaced.

Then you need to replace it.
Any leak in a bladder or diaphragm tank's bladder or diaphragm requires replacing the bladder or diaphragm, and in almost all cases the only way to do that is to buy a new tank.
You didn't specify what tank you have (details matter) but very few tanks have a replaceable bladder (and when I looked at replacing the bladder on one that did, it cost as much as a new tank did, with zero warranty coverage as well as your labor swapping it out, so it was not worth buying in that case.)
The unlikely edge case that @crip659 mentions (leaky valve stem) would be easily detected with soapy water or bubble-blowing solution (available inexpensively as a children's toy or for vastly more money as leak detecting solution in the plumbing aisle.)
